# Find and replace in Notepad++ matching beginning and end of line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to find all lines that follow this format:

```
type="file_one_id"
type="file_two_id"
type="file_three_id"
```

And replace them with a single replacement line:

```
type="my_generic_replacement"
```

The problem is that there are many other lines which also start with `type="file_` or end with `_id"` , so I'm thinking that searching for lines that both begin with `type="file_` **and** end with `_id"` will be required.  Is there a way to do this with notepad++?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could search for `^type="file_.*_id"$` (using Regular Expressions) and replace with `type="my_generic_replacement"`

Answer (score 1):

To replace the lines in Notepad++ you can use this regex:

`type="file_\w+_id"`

To open the window click Search => Replace

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find and replace \r\n and tick Extended in the Replace box; \r\n matches carriage-return + line-feed.
Some systems may only have \r or only \n at the line breaks

Comment: What question are you answering? Why would you replace the linebreaks?

Comment: This answer isn't relevant to the question